# Matcher.quoteReplacement versus preparedstatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, code-injection

In my project I have to create insert statements based on the tables passed.
So I have two options 
1)Write preparedstatement and run it in batch
2)Create insert into table values(..),(..),(..)

I want to know the reasons to prefer (1) over (2) if I use Matcher.quoteReplacement() to escape the values

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Matcher.quoteReplacement` isn't intended to quote SQL strings, so you can't be certain to avoid SQL insertions using it. But even if you had a working quoting function, prepared statements would still be better for several reasons:

- You don't need to worry about forgetting to quote input
- You're not tempted to take a shortcut and not quote values you "know" are safe
- The database can cache the execution plan to avoid parsing similar SQL queries with different parameters, giving a performance boost
- The code gets more readable (IMHO)